# Changing the AWS profile in the aws cli for Windows

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, command-line, aws-cli

I'm using VS Code on Windows. I would like to change the profile from [default] to [scoop]. I run the following commands:

```
aws configure list
```

and it gives me the following output:

```
access_key     ****************BMSB shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************JStS shared-credentials-file
```

I'd like it to display the actual name of the profile, but having worked with AWS for a while I realise that's asking a bit too much, but I can see that this is the [default] profile.

I now want to run a command that will change the context of the cli to [scoop], so I run

```
set AWS_PROFILE scoop
```

(I have also tried this)

```
aws configure set profile scoop
```

I run configure list again to see if the profile has changed, but it hasn't, the same details are returned.

Is it actually possible to do what I'm trying to do? Googling and other Stack Exchange articles imply that there is, but nothing they suggest actually changes the profile. Surely the AWS CLI can't be this poor? If my only option is to copy the [scoop] details into [default] in the credentials file then what's the point of having multiple profiles?

Comment: the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable should control that so I'm guessing the way you're setting it isn't working the way you expect.  You can also pass profile with `aws --profile <profile> ... ` but the AWS_PROFILE environment variable is the way to set it without having to add it to every `aws` invocation.

Comment: Use `set AWS_PROFILE=scoop`. Also, be aware of `aws configure list-profiles` if you want to list all profile names.

Comment: yeah, tried set AWS_PROFILE=scoop as well, didn't work.

Comment: What specifically doesn't work after setting AWS_PROFILE? Run `aws sts get-caller-identity` after setting AWS_PROFILE to see which credentials are in use.

Comment: I'm assuming aws configure list gives the current profile access ID and secret (obfuscated). This doesn't change after I run set AWS_PROFILE.

Comment: Why do you say "I'd like it to display the actual name of the profile"?  `aws configure list` does in fact show the profile name.  Are you using a shell in VS Code's terminal, or a shell in Terminal?  Or something else?  Which shell are you using?  Have you verified the AWS_PROFILE environment variable is actually being set?

Comment: In posix ( read virtually every OS except windows) you'd have to `export AWS_PROFILE` to make it accessible to subprocesses, namely `aws`.  Windows is esoteric so idk if that helps or not